# variables dependent on each other not updating

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get a value from a slider and store it in a variable to then change the size of two squares, as you can see from my code below. I'm getting the `years` variable to update, but for some reason the `mfProportion` and `ifProportion` variables are not updating with it because the size of the square is not changing. If somebody could please take a look and let me know where I went wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerX: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("showing index vs mutual box view")
        addSquares()
    }



    func addSquares() {

        let x = Double(self.view.center.x)
        let y = Double(self.view.center.x)

        let years:Double = 1
        //let mfDollarReturn:Double = pow(1.078, years)
        //let ifDollarReturn:Double = pow(1.098, years)
        //let bankDollarReturn:Double = pow(1.017, years)
        let mfProportion:Double = ((pow(1.078, years))/(pow(1.098, years)))
        let savingsProportion:Double = ((pow(1.017, years))/(pow(1.098, years)))

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let indexSquare = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 250, height: 250))
        indexSquare.text = ""
        indexSquare.center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        indexSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(indexSquare)
        let indexSquareArea:Double = (250*250)

        let mutualSquareDimension:Double = pow((indexSquareArea * mfProportion), 0.500)
        let mutualSquare = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: mutualSquareDimension, height: mutualSquareDimension))
        mutualSquare.center = CGPoint(x: x-(125.00-mutualSquareDimension/2.00), y: y+(125.00-mutualSquareDimension/2.00))
        mutualSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        view.addSubview(mutualSquare)

        let bankSquareDimension:Double = pow((indexSquareArea * savingsProportion), 0.500)
        let bankSquare = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bankSquareDimension, height: bankSquareDimension))
        bankSquare.center = CGPoint(x: x-(125.00-bankSquareDimension/2.00), y: y+(125.00-bankSquareDimension/2.00))
        bankSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view.addSubview(bankSquare)

        slider.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y * 1.5)
        slider.maximumValue = 100
        slider.minimumValue = 1
        slider.value = 1
        view.addSubview(slider)
        slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeValue), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    let slider = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 5))

    @objc func changeValue() {
        let years = Int(slider.value)
        print(years)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here setting `let years = Int(slider.value)` won't change sizes of squares  , you need to re-set frames again according to the new value

```
@objc func changeValue() {
    let years = Int(slider.value)
    print(years)
    // change frames again
}
```

So i highly recommend making a function that add the items as subviews and another 1 that change the frames according to `year` value then call it from `viewDidLoad` and from `changeValue` with `year` value as a parameter